# Applescript/Automator to print on A5 automatically from new files

Tags: printing, applescript, automator

I currently use a paperless program to book jobs in. It will automatically upload to our dropbox folder.

I've been trying to get automator to automatically print new files in the folder then move to the bin. This is working fine, except it keeps printing on a4/too big when we need it to print on a5 paper.

Can anybody help me with this?

I tried creating a folder action with the selected folder, using print finder items, then move finder items to trash.

This works except it won't print to a5 size. I have tried using last used settings on the printer ect when printing normally.

Comment: What type of file are you printing? I don't think that 'last settings' includes paper size. Typically, you would set the page size in the given app. Otherwise, it gets printed to the default paper.